# IPv6: Why changing ScopeId of System.Net.IPAddress is not reflected at ToString() representation?

Tags: c#, ipv6

Yesterday I met a thing that seems as a .NET bug.

```
IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("fe80::1111:2222:abc%11"); // ScopeId is 11

string s1 = addr.ToString(); // I obviously see fe80::1111:2222:abc%11
addr.ScopeId = 0; // ScopeId is zero from now
string s2 = addr.ToString(); // I expect to see fe80::1111:2222:abc
```

Why `s1` is the same content as `s2` even after the `ScopeId` is changed? In debugger Watch window I see that scope value is really changed. But internal string field has no impact.

For sure, I tried this with various IPv6 addresses and different scope IDs - behavior is the same. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

I would call this a bug in the .NET Framework.

If you look at the source code for the IPAddress class:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs

You'll see that the `.ToString()` method actually caches the results to a private field called `m_ToString`.  However, if you then look at the setter for the `ScopeId` property, you see that it changes the private fields for `m_ScopeId` and `m_Address`, but it does not clear the `m_ToString` value.

If you look at the Address property, you'll see that they clear the `m_ToString` field when that property is set.

If you want a work around, you can do what they did here:

[How do you determine equality between two IPv6 addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787530/how-do-you-determine-equality-between-two-ipv6-addresses)

by using the `.GetAddressBytes()` method to pass to the constructor to create a new instance. This will give you a `ScopeId` of zero.

Comment: I opened the following Microsoft Connect Bug:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/952868